# imageview issue in relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

if i run this code statically, i.e simply create a sample programme and do setcontentview it works well.

But if i inflate this view and display as listview item. the image view does not stretches. I need a black color strip to be appear at the extreme left corner of width 10dp and it should fill the view like a line. for each item.

Also note, if i do    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" like this to my item layout, it works ok. But the item contents are not fully displayed, it get truncated at specific height.

I'm inflating my view like this

```
convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(com.meganext.googletaskclient.R.layout.layout_list_item, parent, false);
```

Here is my layout, which i'm inflating on listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="10dp"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:adjustViewBounds="false"
         android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
         android:id="@+id/ID_task_item_priority"

         android:src="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Tasks TitleTasks TitleTasks TitleTasks Title Tasks TitleTasks TitleTasks Title"
         android:id="@+id/ID_task_item_title"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ID_task_item_priority"
         android:singleLine="true"
         android:ellipsize="end"

         android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
         android:textSize="25sp"
        />

    <TextView 

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ID_task_item_notes"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ID_task_item_title"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ID_task_item_priority"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="Task descriptionTask descriptionTask descriptionTask descriptionTask descriptionTask descriptionTask descriptionTask description"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/id_due_date"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ID_task_item_notes"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="10-2-2014"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />

         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/ID_task_item_is_completed_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ID_task_item_title"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ID_task_item_title"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

My listview code is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


     <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/home_activity">
    </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

output.

[image]

Comment: the width is `10dp` do you want the height to be `10dp` instead?

Comment: No, i need the height to be fill_parent, that should be list item height.

Comment: @Raghunandan, if i do android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" like this to my item layout, it works ok. But the item contents are not fully displayed, it get truncated at specific height.

Comment: @Raghunandan, I HAVE UPDATED THE IMAGE. PLEASE HAVE A LOOK ONCE. THANKS

Comment: Not that it is specifically answering your question, but why are you using an ImageView if you aren't actually setting an image to the view. If you just want a black background it is more efficient to just use a view with a background color of black.

Comment: i tried with simple view also, it didn't work. it just gave a small strip at left. its not filling parent in listview item

Comment: Did you try stting your views layout to alignParentLeft? And is the output image what you want or what you are getting?

Comment: Yes, i tried no luck :(

Comment: i'm getting a small strip at left side. thats all. it looks very thin

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/ID_task_item_priority"
        android:src="@android:color/black"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tasks TitleTasks TitleTasks TitleTasks Title Tasks TitleTasks TitleTasks Title"
            android:id="@+id/ID_task_item_title"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ID_task_item_notes"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Task descriptionTask descriptionTask descriptionTask descriptionTask descriptionTask descriptionTask descriptionTask description"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/id_due_date"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="10-2-2014"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/ID_task_item_is_completed_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, i will try this way & let you know. Thanks harish. Also harish one more thing i want to know, why cant we use imageview inside relativelayout like that?, why the color wont fill though we specify fill_parent there?

Comment: You easily manage your requirement using LinearLayout that y i arrange layout using LinearLayout if RelativeLayout is not mandatory for you then use as above otherwise i also try to achieved your requirement using RelativeLayout yet RelativeLayout is quite difficult to understood.

Comment: Ok, haresh, Thanks i will surely test your layout and let you know. For me relative layout is not mandatory. Thanks Haresh. But if you get solution for relative layout please please let me know. Did u get my issue right?. you can easily replicate in a sample example. Thanks for the support bro

Comment: Hi Haresh, i checked thanks, in this image is stretching but the issue is my date text is not moving to extreme end. If i try to do by designer its not at all moving. its just belo description, any inputs on how we can do. & also why relative layout wont work in this way?